# React-Table getting data of a specific row

Tags: reactjs, react-table

i am new to the react.
 i used react-table to show the data i have. Now i need to take a specific data from my table suppose name from last viewIndex value that i have.How could i do it? i want the last row data while i doing pagination,that is in all pages;

```
<ReactTable
              columns={columns}
              data={this.state.users}
              defaultPageSize={3}
              className="-striped -highlight"
              sortable={false}
              resizable={false}
              style={{
                textAlign: "center"
              }}


            />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the viewIndex from the column.

```
const columns = [
 {
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name',
    Cell: e => {
      console.log(e) // viewIndex here
      return e.original.name
    }
]
```

After that you can filter this.state.users by index or name.